# Containerized Kafka client errors when producing messages to the host Kafka server

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

There are a number of similar types of queries on stackoverflow, but none quite match the problem that I am seeing.

I have a zookeeper/kafka setup on my server which work perfectly.  One can produce

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.2.80:9092 --topic test
```

and consume

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.2.80:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

locally on the Linux Ubuntu 16.04 server.

From a Docker container - also running Ubuntu 16.04 - I want to produce and consume.  The container's Kafka code was copied from that on the server.
Firstly I can create a new topic

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.2.80:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test2
```

from the container and then list it again

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 192.168.2.80:2181
```

However when I try to produce new messages, using the above (kafka-console-producer.sh) command it fails with the following message:

```
[2017-06-05 13:59:05,317] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2  with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test2-0: 1526 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

immediately after entering the text of the message and pressing enter.

It may seem strange running a Docker container on the same host, but once this works I will move the container to a separate host for production.

My kafka server.properties file:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

Kafka version:

```
2.12-0.10.2.1
```

Docker version:

```
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
```

Comment: If you use mac and docker-machine on your host, you have to do port forwarding:
docker-machine ssh default -L 9092:localhost:9092 -L 2181:localhost:2181

Comment: and also what image of Kafka do you use? this one works for me: https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

Comment: Thanks Andy,
I am trying to keep things simple.  So I have just downloaded it using this link:

    wget ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/kafka/0.10.2.1/kafka_2.12-0.10.2.1.tgz

Using tar it then unpacks zookeeper and kafka in one go.  It seems to work well on my main Ubuntu server.
Then I did the same thing inside my Ubuntu:latest docker image.  However, all I am running inside the container are the commands in the kafka bin directory.  I haven't started either of the daemons for zookeeper or kafka.

Answer (score 39):

The problem is (slightly simplified) caused by how Kafka's protocol works.  Given a list of "bootstrap servers" (e.g. `localhost:9092`), a Kafka client will contact those bootstrap servers, but then use the hostnames of the actual Kafka brokers *as returned by the bootstrap servers* (the broker's `advertised.listeners` config, depending on your Kafka/Docker setup, might be set to e.g. `kafka:9092`).  So here, the client would talk to `localhost:9092` for bootstrapping (which will work), but then switch to `kafka:9092` (which will not work, "thanks" to the networking setup).

Fortunately there is a way to configure Kafka + Docker in a way that "just works", and it doesn't require shenanigans such as fiddling with your host's `/etc/hosts` file and such.  As part of this you need to set a few (new) Kafka settings though, which were added in kafka's [KIP-103: Separation of Internal and External traffic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-103%3A+Separation+of+Internal+and+External+traffic).

Here's a snippet for Docker Compose (`docker-compose.yml`) that demonstrates how to do this:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:3.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '32181:32181'
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:3.2.1
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '29092:29092'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      # Following line is needed for Kafka versions 0.11+
      # in case you run less than 3 Kafka brokers in your
      # cluster because the broker config
      # `offsets.topic.replication.factor` (default: 3)
      # is now enforced upon topic creation
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

Here, the key settings are:

- `listener.security.protocol.map` (which is being set via `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP`)
- `inter.broker.listener.name`
- `advertised.listeners`

In the setup above, the containerized Kafka broker listens on `localhost:9092` for access from your host machine (e.g. your Mac laptop) and on `kafka:29092` for access from other containers.

A full end-to-end example is available at:
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/v3.2.1/examples/kafka-streams-examples/docker-compose.yml (documentation at http://docs.confluent.io/3.2.1/cp-docker-images/docs/tutorials/kafka-streams-examples.html).

Comment: Thanks Michael,
I think this post will be very helpful when I start on the next stage whichwill require using docker-compose to get my configuration up and running.

Comment: Is it necessary to use two separate ports for host and container? My container still says its not able to connect

Comment: Yes, you need to use two separate ports.

Comment: Great answer - pity there's only one upvote. It explains the problem, the reasons, a not-recommended solution and a working fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your producer (in the container) can't resolve the host name of your Linux guest OS which is returned in the Kafka producers initial metadata request to the bootstrap server. You can add it manually to the /etc/hosts file inside the container or add "--add-host" parameter to the docker run command that launches the image running your producer

Comment: Thank you Hans.

I need to clarify that the Ubuntu server runs zookeeper and kafka not inside a container.  From inside the container I am running the kafka bin scripts, there is no kafka server inside the container.

I've made the change you suggested:
Adding 192.168.2.80 into the container's /etc/host file with the name of the server I get from echo $HOSTNAME.  I've tested it works inside the container using 'ping server_name'.

But I am still getting the same error message described in my message above.

Comment: If I run the producer script from another server, not inside a container, it works correctly as expected.  That server does not have an entry in its /etc/hosts file for the kakfa server's host.

Answer (score 0):

Aha!
After further reading and the answers given above the solution came. As is often the case it is an easy one.
A simple edit of the kafka server.properties file:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.2.80:9092
```

Also note, the parameter 'listeners' is not set in this file.

Comment: Most probably this won't work in the sense that e.g. you may be able to talk from your host machine (e.g. Mac laptop) to your containerized broker, but other containers may not be able to talk to the broker.  The "trick" to make it work, out of the box, for both your host machine and also for other containerized services that depend on Kafka is what I explained in my answer above.

Comment: what is this PLAINTEXT?